# Problema al iniciar mi aplicación de mapa - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**AppFlutter**

Estoy trabajando una app como googlemaps para que muestre mi ubicación al abrir la app, estoy usando googlemapsfluter para mostrar el mapa, la aplicacion **funciona bien cuando le mando LatLng estáticas**, pero cuando le pongo una ubicacion en tiempo real usando el pack geolocalizador, me **da un error como si no ejecutara el metodo para obtener mi ubicacion en tiempo real.**

**he realizado prueba y cuando lo ejecuto desde un boton para mostrar mi ubicacion en tiempo real corre bien la app, pero cuando quiero ejecutarlo sin boton al iniciar app me da un error.**

cualquiere ayuda por favor, gracias por su tiempo.

```
 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

 static final String routename = 'home';

 @override
_HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

final geoBloc = new GeoBloc();
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
Set<Marker> _markers = Set<Marker>();
Set <Polyline> _polylines = Set<Polyline>();  
Set <Circle> _circulo = Set<Circle>();
List <LatLng> polylineCoordinates = []; 
// PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints ();
var puntoA = LatLng(-17.760178, -63.051630);   
var puntoB = LatLng(-17.760128, -63.051794);
var puntoC = LatLng(-17.760091, -63.052104);
Geolocation valla1 = 
Geolocation(latitude:-17.760178,longitude:-63.051630,radius: 15,id: ' 
GeoVallaA');
Geolocation valla2 = 
 Geolocation(latitude:-17.760128,longitude:-63.051794,radius: 15,id: 
'GeoVallaB');
MapType _mapaActual = MapType.hybrid;
final scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
String geoUbicacion;

void initState() {
 super.initState();
 _ubicacionActual();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 final geo = GeoModel(valor:geoUbicacion);

 return Scaffold(  
    key: scaffoldkey,  
    appBar: AppBar( 
      title: Text('Ruta Trufi Piedades'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.local_hospital),
          onPressed: (){ },
        )
      ],
    ),
    drawer: MenuWidget(),
    body: _crearFlutterMapa(geo),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: _crearBotonFlotante(context),
 );
}

Widget _crearBotonFlotante(BuildContext context){

return FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.map),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    mini: true,
    onPressed:(){
      _mapaActual = _mapaActual == MapType.hybrid
                                ? MapType.normal
                                :MapType.hybrid;
      setState((){});
     }
   );
 }


Widget _crearFlutterMapa(GeoModel geo){

 return GoogleMap(
  mapType: _mapaActual,
  myLocationEnabled: true,
  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: geo.coordenadaLatLog(),
    zoom: 15.0
  ),
  markers:_markers,
  circles: _circulo,
  polylines: _polylines,
  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller)
  {
    _controller.complete(controller);
     setState(() {
      _crearMarcador();
      _crearCirculo();
      // _initPlatformState(geo);
      // _crearLineaRuta();
      });
    },
  );
}

_ubicacionActual() async {

 Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: 
 LocationAccuracy.high);
 geoUbicacion = position.latitude.toString() +','+ 
 position.longitude.toString();

}
```

Comment: Debes mostrar lo que has intentado para que te puedan ayudar, sin código no es posible saber lo que esta sucediendo con exactitud y también agrega si te sale algún tipo de error.

Comment: Necesitas solicitar los permisos de gps primero

Comment: los permisos tengo configurado en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: es decir, tienes que solicitar los permisos de GPS en runtime https://dev.to/ahmedcharef/flutter-wait-user-enable-gps-permission-location-4po2